# Android AppWidget Updating

Tags: java, android

I have code:

```
int i = 0;
while(true){
i++;

remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1,  "" +  i );
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code refresh my widget, but only 12 times. When "i" reaches 12 nothing happens. How to fix it?

Comment: Is it the whole loop ?

Answer (score 0):

It is limited by the Android os system:

follow this android api link : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Android Api says:

> The updatePeriodMillis attribute defines how often the App Widget
>   framework should request an update from the AppWidgetProvider by
>   calling the onUpdate() callback method. The actual update is not
>   guaranteed to occur exactly on time with this value and we suggest
>   updating as infrequently as possible—perhaps no more than once an hour
>   to conserve the battery. You might also allow the user to adjust the
>   frequency in a configuration—some people might want a stock ticker to
>   update every 15 minutes, or maybe only four times a day.